# CompletableFuture return totally different future

Tags: java-8, future

I am researching about Java 8 CompletableFuture (Promise in languages like Scala or JS).

May be I've done something wrong or didn't not found any description of this. Future that returned after setup few callbacks on it return completely independent future.

I have some unit test for that:

```
public class FutureTest {
    private boolean stage1;
    private boolean stage2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.stage1 = false;
        this.stage2 = false;
    }

    @Test
    public void testCombinationOfCallbacks() throws Exception {
        final CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

        future
            .whenComplete((s, e) -> stage1 = true)
            .whenComplete((s, e) -> stage2 = true);

        future.complete("done");

        assertTrue(stage1);
        assertTrue(stage2);
        assertEquals("done", future.get());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCombinationOfCallbacksCalledOnReturnedFuture() throws Exception {
        final CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

        final CompletableFuture<String> returnedFuture = future
                .whenComplete((s, e) -> stage1 = true)
                .whenComplete((s, e) -> stage2 = true);

        returnedFuture.complete("done");

        assertFalse(future.isDone());
        assertFalse(stage1);
        assertFalse(stage2);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the second test, the initially created future isn't affected by fact of completion of future with callbacks. So basically callbacks are setup on future that was created, but not returning future.

It means that you have never do something like this:

```
private CompletableFuture<String> createFuture() {
    return new CompletableFuture<String>()
        .whenComplete((s, e) -> stage1 = true)
        .whenComplete((s, e) -> stage2 = true);
}
```

Is it documented somewhere in the JavaDocs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadocs say what the methods *can* do, not the infinite amount of other things they can't do:

> ```
>     public CompletionStage<T> whenComplete
>     (BiConsumer<? super T, ? super Throwable> action);
> ```
>
> Returns a **new** CompletionStage with the same result or exception
>   as this stage, and when this stage completes, executes the
>   given action with the result (or {@code null} if none) and the
>   exception (or {@code null} if none) of this stage.
>   
>   @param action the action to perform
>   @return the **new** CompletionStage

The docs say you create a new  `CompletionStage` (which `CompleteableFuture` implements) with each invocation of `whenComplete` and they only mention forward-propagation of results from the old stage to the new stage.

You can only assume that the methods do what the docs describe.

What you were expecting is backwards propagation from the new stage to the old stage, which clearly *isn't mentioned* anywhere in the javadocs and thus you shouldn't be expecting that behavior in the first place.